# Trying do solve it but dont getting anything printed to the console

Tags: java

> Write a method shouldWakeUp that has 2 parameters.
>
> 1st parameter should be of type boolean and be named barking it represents if our dog is currently //barking.
>
> 2nd parameter represents the hour of the day and is of type int with the name hourOfDay and has a //valid range of 0-23.
>
> We have to wake up if the dog is barking before 8 or after 22 hours so in that case return true.
>
> In all other cases return false.
>
> If the hourOfDay parameter is less than 0 or greater than 23 return false.

Examples of input/output:

- shouldWakeUp (true, 1); → should return true
- shouldWakeUp (false, 2); → should return false since the dog is not barking.
- shouldWakeUp (true, 8); → should return false, since it's not before 8.
- shouldWakeUp (true, -1); → should return false since the hourOfDay parameter needs to be in a range //0-23.

---

```
public class BarkingDog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // calling the method 
        shouldWakeUp(true, 25 );
        shouldWakeUp(true, 1 );
    }

    public static boolean shouldWakeUp ( boolean barking, int hourOfDay) {
        //hours 
        if (hourOfDay < 0 || hourOfDay > 23) {
            return false;
        } else if (hourOfDay < 8 || hourOfDay > 22) {
            if (barking) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: None of your code tries to prints anything to the console, it appears to be working as expected.

Comment: maybe a small mistake in hourOfDay > 22. I think it should be >=.

Comment: `if (cond) { return true; } else { return false; }` results in same as `return cond;`, but that wont help since there is no output statement like `System.out.println(something);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting any output because you are not printing it. Simply calling the function and not catching the result.

```
System.out.println(shouldWakeUp(true, 25 ));
```

Also, you can imprve your method logic to simply

```
public static boolean shouldWakeUp ( boolean isBarking, int hourOfDay){
    return isBarking && ((hourOfDay < 8 && hourOfDay >= 0) || (hourOfDay > 22 && hourOfDay <= 23));
}
```